# Section name with spaces

Tags: sectioning

How do I create a section with spaces, and then properly close it?

```
\section{Name with Space}
.....
\Name with Space
```

I am getting an error.

On the template I see

```
\section*{Bibliography}
....
\bibliography{sample} % here the Bibliography is ended from above
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid it's not clear to me what your objective is. Unless you use a completely idiosyncratic document class, the instruction `\section{Name with Space}` will typeset the string "Name with Space" in bold (and probably with a section number prefixed to it) with spaces between the words -- as most would expect it to do. Separately, how is the macro `\Name` defined? Finally, please be more specific about what you mean by "properly closing it"?

Comment: after reviewing a template, I see `\section*{Bibliography}
....
\bibliography{sample}`. So I assume that to include a section, you need an end, much like `<HTML></HTML>, but in Latex, you close with the newly created section name

Comment: LaTeX is *not* like HTML. In particular, LaTeX has instructions, such as `\section{<Some title>}`, that do not need to be terminated at all. It's somewhat misleading to think of the "scope" of a `\section` command as somehow extending beyond its immediate task, which is to typeset the section header (plus take care of some further housekeeping details). In a syntactic sense, the "scope" of a section ends with a new section or higher-level sectioning block, say chapter or part. However, LaTeX provides no means for enforcing such notions at the sectioning stage.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you would use some good reading on LaTeX for beginners, since this is quite a basic part of LaTeX's concept. We have a [summary of good books](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex), from my personal taste, I would recommend [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english).

Comment: Your edit contains another general misconception. The `\bibliography` macro does not end the 'Bibliography' section. Instead, it provides the information which `.bib` file (the actual database containing sources) is going to be used by BibTeX.